# Continually erasing a string leads to an infinite loop

Tags: c++, linux, stdstring

What I am trying to do is take a path in and then continually erase the path directory by directory, checking to see if it is a symbolic link at any point. Here is what I have:

```
static bool isLinkDirInSymLink (std::string linkPath)
    {
    DIR *baseDir;
    struct dirent *currentDir;

    do
        {
        baseDir = opendir(linkPath.c_str());
        if (baseDir)
            {
            currentDir = readdir(baseDir);
            if (currentDir->d_type == DT_LNK)
                return true;
            }
        linkPath.erase (linkPath.find_last_of("/") + 1, linkPath.find_first_of("\0"));
        } while (strcmp(linkPath.c_str(), "") != 0);

    return false;
    }
```

This gets stuck in an infinite loop. When I run the program in `gdb` what happens is I send in a `linkPath` of `/home/user/test/linktest/out/mDirs/testDir1/test`, when this successfully erases and I am left with is  `/home/user/test/linktest/out/mDirs/testDir1`, however this is where the infinite loop begins. Even though this is in the same format as the first path when it goes into `erase`, nothing happens. I have tried many different variations of `erase` from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) but none seem to work. I have also tried `linkPath.append('\0')` because I thought maybe it was an issue with the null character at the end.

Thanks everyone, this is what I ended up with:

```
char realPath[MAX_FILELENGTH];

do
    {
    if (realpath (linkPath.c_str(), realPath) != NULL)
        if (strcmp(linkPath.c_str(), realPath) != 0)
            return true;

    size_t eraseFrom = linkPath.rfind('/');
    if (std::string::npos != eraseFrom)
        linkPath.erase(eraseFrom);
    } while ( !linkPath.empty() );

return false;
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and stepping through?

Comment: What is the type of linkPath ? Can you show how it is declared?

Comment: @SergeRogatch it's the function's parameter.

Comment: Instead of `linkPath.find_first_of("\0")`, use `std::string::npos`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the `+ 1` in you erase call, you are erasing characters from one past the `/` to just before the end of the string, erasing the following characters:

```
/home/user/test/linktest/out/mDirs/testDir1/test\0
                                            ^^^^
```

The first iteration of the loop will remove `test`, leaving you with `/home/user/test/linktest/out/mDirs/testDir1/`. All subsequent calls to `erase` will do nothing, because there are zero characters between `/` and `\0`.

You should remove the `+ 1` from `linkPath.find_last_of("/") + 1` in your erase call, so that the trailing slash is removed as well.

Moreover, the `erase(size_t, size_t)` overload actually takes the *length* of the part to erase as the second argument - `find_first_of` returns the index of the found character, not an iterator to it. Your code works only by accident. Use `std::string::npos`, which will erase everything until the end, instead of the position of the `\0` character (which may not be present in the string if you haven't called `c_str()` yet).

Answer (score 3):

```
linkPath.find_last_of("/") + 1
```

Should just be;

```
linkPath.find_last_of("/")
```

The first erase leaves a trailing `/` in place, so the next erase attempts to erase from the end of the string to the end, hence the loop. The erase should include the directory separator `/`.

The `linkPath.find_first_of("\0")` is not needed, you can just use `npos` to remove to the end of the string. The use of the `find_first_of` gives a size type result, so the following form of erase is used `basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you missed the trailing slash when looking in the debugger. This could be better:

```
linkPath.erase (linkPath.begin()+linkPath.find_last_of("/"), linkPath.end());
```

There was another problem that wrong overload of `std::string::erase` was called: #1 in [this list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) ("pos+len"), while you likely intended #3 ("range"). That happens because [std::string::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) returns `size_t`, not an iterator. Alternatively, to save typing you can use this:

```
linkPath.resize(linkPath.find_last_of("/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something as the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string linkPath( "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590945/"
                          "continually-erasing-string-leads-to-infinite-loop" );

    do
    {
        std::cout << linkPath << std::endl;

        auto n = linkPath.rfind( '/' );
        n = n == std::string::npos ? 0 : n;

        linkPath.erase( n );
    } while ( !linkPath.empty() );        
}
```

The program output is

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590945/continually-erasing-string-leads-to-infinite-loop
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590945
http://stackoverflow.com/questions
http://stackoverflow.com
http:/
http:
```

Of course you can modify the code as you like. It demonstrates an approach to the task.

As for your code then this call

```
linkPath.find_first_of("\0")
```

will always return `std::string::npos`. So it does not male sense. 
And using this expression

```
linkPath.find_last_of("/") + 1
```

will always keep the first found character '/' in the string.

Answer (score 0):

A more correct and simplified implementation

```
static bool isLinkDirInSymLink(std::string linkPath) {
    DIR * baseDir;
    struct dirent * currentDir;
    do {
        baseDir = opendir(linkPath.c_str());
        if (baseDir) {
            currentDir = readdir(baseDir);
            if (currentDir->d_type == DT_LNK) return true;
        }
        std::string::size_type it = linkPath.rfind('/');
        if (it != std::string::npos) linkPath.erase(it);
    } while (!linkPath.empty());
    return false;
}
```